# How many non-isomorphic abelian groups of order $\kappa$ are there for $\kappa$ infinite?

Tags: cardinals, abelian-groups

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal. How many non-isomorphic abelian groups of order (cardinality) $\kappa$ are there?

For finite $\kappa,$ we can use the classification theorem and obtain the number of non-isomorphic abelian groups of this order in finite time. I don't think there is a classification theorem for general infinite abelian groups, but I think this cannot be a difficult problem, since cardinality questions are generally easier for infinite sets than for finite sets. Nevertheless, I have no idea how to solve it.

**EDIT** If this is actually difficult, perhaps this question isn't:

For a cardinal number $\kappa,$ is there always a cardinal $\lambda$ such that there are more non-isomorphic abelian groups of order $\lambda$ than those of order $\kappa\,?$

Comment: I'd think this might be dependent on your choice of axioms (e.g., if you assume Martin's Axiom+$2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_1$, then you have a non-free Whitehead group of size $\aleph_1$, while if you assume $\lozenge$ you don't).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for the comment. This is above me, but I have added a new, possibly less problematic, question.

Comment: You should add nontriviality to that edit. I can easily think of $\omega$ many non-isomorphic groups of any infinite size ($\bigoplus_\kappa\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not sure why this makes my question trivial. You give $\omega$ groups of size $\kappa.$ Suppose these are all for a particular $\kappa.$ Can I find a cardinal $\lambda$ such that there are _strictly_ more non-isomorphic abelian groups than $\omega$? You just say that I'll find another cardinal $\lambda$ for which there are at least $\omega$ such groups of size $\lambda.$

Comment: I'll just write a "temporary" answer.

Comment: There is a trivial upper bound: for infinite cardinality $\kappa$, there can be at most $\kappa$ groups by counting the number of possible multiplication tables.

Comment: @JohannesKloos: How is that compatible with my answer for $\kappa=\omega$?

Comment: @Johannes: Since a multiplication table is a function from $G \times G \rightarrow G$, the obvious upper bound on the number of multiplication tables is $\kappa^{\kappa^2} = 2^{\kappa}$ for infinite $\kappa$.  I suspect that this upper bound is obtained for all infinite cardinals, and I am almost sure it is for $\kappa = \aleph_0$.

Comment: @Pete & Asaf: you are right, this should have been $2^\kappa$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's known by Fisher, Eklof and Shelah (see theorem 2.1 in [1]) that there are abelian groups which are stable but not superstable. Another well known result of Shelah (see [2]) is that, roughly speaking (again, check the paper below for details), if $T$ is not superstable, then $T$ has $2^{\lambda}$ non isomorphic models of cardinality $\lambda$. These two results combined imply the existence of $2^{\lambda}$ non-isomorphic abelian groups of cardinality $\lambda$.

---

**Bibliography:**

1. J. T. Baldwin and Jan Saxl (1976). **[Logical stability in group theory.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700018553)** *Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society* (Series A), 21 , pp 267-276.
2. S. Shelah (1974). **[Why There Are Many Nonisomorphic Models for Unsuperstable Theories.](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1974.1/Main/icm1974.1.0259.0264.ocr.pdf)** *Proceedings of the International Congress of Mathematicians* (Vol I), pp 259-264.

Comment: I can't find the first paper. Can you give a real citation and not a link?

Comment: The paper's title is "Logical stability in group theory", the authors are John Baldwin and Jan Saxl. You should find it easily on google.

Comment: This definitely answers the question.  Still, I have to think that somewhat less artillery should suffice: e.g. a proof which uses abelian group theory only and does not appeal to work of the leading model theorist of our time.

Answer (score 6):

To your edit, this may depend on the value of the continuum, let us fix $\kappa$ to be an infinite cardinal, and $\mathbb P$ the set of primes in $\mathbb N$.

Denote for $p$ prime, denote the group $A_p=\bigoplus\limits_{i<\kappa}\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

Now for every $I\subseteq\mathbb P$ denote the group $Z_I=\bigoplus\limits_{p\in I}A_p$. Its cardinality is $\kappa$. If $I\neq J$ then without loss of generality there is some $n\in I\setminus J$, therefore in $Z_I$ there is an element of order $n$, while in $Z_J$ there are none of order $n$.

This shows that there are *at least* continuum many non-isomorphic subgroups. And I haven't began meddling with free abelian groups and other strange animals. Moreover the larger $\kappa$ gets the more "smaller" groups we can use. I'd conjecture that the number either ends up $2^{\kappa}$ many, or its representation is independent of ZFC (it has no representation as a function of $\kappa$ in terms of $\aleph$ cardinals and the continuum function).

Comment: Thanks. So for any cardinal number $\kappa,$ I will find at least continuum groups of order $\kappa.$ But will I find a $\lambda$ such that there are (for example) at least $2^{\mathfrak c}$ abelian groups of this order?

Comment: @ymar: I've added my conjecture that you can always find $2^\kappa$ many. In particular for $\kappa>\mathfrak c$ your answer would be positive.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two observations:

1) The number of isomorphism classes of abelian groups of infinite cardinality $\kappa$ is at most the number of "group laws" on a set of cardinality $\kappa$, which is at most 
the number of functions $\kappa \times \kappa \rightarrow \kappa$, which is 
$\kappa^{\kappa^2} = 2^{\kappa}$.

2) There are $2^{\aleph_0}$ abelian groups of cardinality $\aleph_0$.  Indeed, let $\mathcal{P}$ be the prime numbers, and for any subset $S \subset \mathcal{P}$, let 
$G_S = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \bigoplus_{p \in S} \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

The argument of part 2) doesn't seem to adapt so well to higher cardinalities, but off the top of my head I will guess that there are $2^{\kappa}$ isomorphism classes of abelian groups of cardinality $\kappa$ for all $\kappa \geq \aleph_0$.

(**Added**: Well, 2) adapts to higher cardinalities in the following anemic sense: for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, we can take $G_S = \bigoplus_{\kappa} \mathbb{Z} \oplus \bigoplus_{p \in S} \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ to see that there are at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ isomorphism classes of cardinality $\kappa$ abelian groups.  This is awfully similar to what Asaf wrote above; for some reason it took me a little while to process his answer.  I also suspect that the question can be answered by bringing out the **Ulm invariants** and their possible values, but the number of people who are conversant which such things may be rather small.  E.g., not me...)

Comment: Are there arbitrarily large rings "like" $\mathbb{Z}$?  "Like" means "your proof of $2)$ goes through identically using $R$ and $R/pR$ as $p$ ranges over the primes (or irreducibles, or whatever) of $R$".  Perhaps an Lowenheim-Skolem type argument works?  (I am just thinking out loud).

Comment: @Jason: I think I may have an argument which by transfinite induction shows that indeed there are $2^\kappa$ many non-isomorphic groups. Alas, the server is being a jerk so I'll wait until it's working properly again before posting it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Please do! I was never taught transfinite induction but I have a book that explains it at length, so with its assistance, I hope I might be able to understand your argument.

Comment: @ymar: I don't think my argument carries over well enough. Perhaps with additional assumptions on the behavior of infinite sets it is possible to carry the argument - but I am not sure what those would be, or how to prove that.

Comment: That's too bad... :( Perhaps it would still be possible to answer the question in the edit?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the second (easier) question is yes, I believe. If I have made any serious mistakes in the following argument, comments are more than welcome.

In $\mathrm {ZFC}$ any set can be well-ordered, so we can assume all cardinals are aleph numbers. So, suppose for some cardinal number $\kappa$ we have $\aleph_\alpha$ non-isomorphic abelian groups of order $\kappa$. Let $\omega_\alpha$ be the initial ordinal of $\aleph_\alpha$ and let $\lambda>\max\lbrace\aleph_{\omega_{\alpha+1}},\kappa\rbrace$ be any cardinal number. For every ordinal number $\beta<\omega_{\alpha+1}$ define: $$A_\beta=(\bigoplus\limits_{i<\omega_\beta}\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)\oplus(\bigoplus\limits_{i<\lambda}\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)$$ Now, because of the second (bigger) summand, $A_\beta$ has order $\lambda$. Because of the first summand, $A_\beta$ contains exactly $\aleph_\beta$ elements of order $2$. Hence, for $\beta_1\neq\beta_2$, $A_{\beta_1}$ and $A_{\beta_2}$ cannot be isomorphic. Since there are $\aleph_{\alpha+1}>\aleph_{\alpha}$ such ordinals $\beta$, we have found a cardinal $\lambda>\kappa$ such that there are more non-isomorphic abelian groups of order $\lambda$ than of order $\kappa$.

Comment: Yes, this works to answer the "easier question": nicely done.